# Service installer by WiX

Tags: windows-services, wix, installation

I have a Windows service installer. It can install and is working correctly on my machine.
But it gives an error when installing on a client machine. The error as follows:

> Verify that you have sufficient privileges to start system services.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: First thing to try would be running your setup as administrator.

Comment: I have tried that option also..not working

Answer (score 2):

Debug your service installer using the information in [the answer to Stack Overflow question *Failed to install and start Windows services in WiX installer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16191909/1124244) to find the root cause of the issue.